# JS loop window.location and match a part of property

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to loop a window.location and match a certain part and delete it?

I will explain what I want to achieve. I'm adding and deleting properties like below. However if I add a new property like 'modal_test' I dont want to add a new hardcoded line.

```
delete window.location.modal_page;
delete window.location.modal_search;
delete window.location.modal_ext_search;
delete window.location.modal_id;
```

I can loop below to get all the properties.

```
for (const property in window.location) {
  // need to match modal_* and delete it
  // Or match against not only modal_* but also other properties ['modal_*', 'guid', 'id']
  console.log(property);
}
```

Comment: The location object does not have those properties [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) - why do you use the window.location as your storage object?

Comment: `if (property.startsWith('modal_')) { ... }`

Comment: Because I found it handy to store them in that and if I open lets say a modal and want to fetch data I use window.location.modal_id that I fill when the onclick to open the modal is triggered

Comment: What do you gain by putting it in `window.location` rather than just using a normal global variable?

Comment: You would find it handier to store your data in a global variable in it's own right. You would then not need to loop through anything to delete it...

Comment: Not another global var. Its also nothing to lose to put it in window.location like I use it. Just a matter off taste

Comment: It is not "handy" to store something in a built-in property of window. Just do `const myModalStorage = {}; myModalStorage.modal_page = 'page1';` Otherwise you will confuse anyone coming after AND people at SO you ask to help

Comment: What you are losing is the ability to easily delete your values. Plus putting it window.location is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the properties that you want to delete in an array and loop over them:

```
let propertiesToDelete = ['modal_page','modal_search','modal_ext_search','modal_id']
    
 propertiesToDelete.forEach(property=> delete window.location[property])
```